# How to get Equivalent class depends on user input?

Tags: java, jena

My RDF:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Isolator">
  <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/VibrationAbsorber"/>
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/MagnetoRheological(MR)damper">
  <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/**SemiActiveDamper**"/>
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

And my code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException,InterruptedException {

// create an empty model
 OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM,null);

// use the class loader to find the input file
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
if (in == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
}

// read the RDF/XML files
m.read( in, "" );

Scanner user_input=new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
System.out.print("Enter your concept");
input= user_input.next();

ExtendedIterator<?> i1 = m.listClasses();
while(i1.hasNext()){
 OntClass oc = (OntClass)i1.next();

 if( oc.getEquivalentClass() != null){
   input=oc.getEquivalentClass().toString();
 System.out.println("Equivalent Class name: "+oc.getEquivalentClass().getLocalName());
  }
}
```

Using this code, I got a list of equivalent classes, for example SemiActiveDamper and VibrationAbsorber. But my target is only to get SemiActiveDamper or VibrationAbsorber according to user input.  How could I solve this problem?

Comment: As the answers on both this site and on answers.semanticweb.com point out, you could do a string comparison on the IRIs of the classes, or better yet, use nicer labels and compare those.  However, it's not clear at all here _how_ you're trying to use `input`.  You do `input = user_input.next();` and then, without ever using the value of `input`, reassign with `input = oc.getEquivalentClass().toString();`.  Is this a question about RDF and Jena, or a question about how to compare strings in Java?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor its about RDF and Jena.

Comment: Accept my apologies if that seemed like a trivial question, but I asked because there there's no actual string comparison occurring in the code you pasted, so it seemed like it might have been a question about how to compare strings.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i am beginner level, i got your point and i think it should be compare strings

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/24208/how-to-get-equivalent-class-depends-on-user-input](https://web.archive.org/web/20131026060413/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/24208/how-to-get-equivalent-class-depends-on-user-input)

use string comparison on the URi of the equivalent class

Better - add user readable labels to the classes and search on those.